# Abort the whole test set execution programmatically?

Tags: abort, hp-uft, alm

**How can I abort the whole test set's execution from within a script?**

I have a library which, if it encounters certain circumstances, comes to the conclusion that further test execution does not make any sense. The "hardest" abort I know is `ExitTest`, but it only aborts the current test's execution, not the whole test set.

I understand I could map this to test dependencies in the test set, *but* those should be used only to model business-driven dependencies between tests, to coordinate parallel test execution, as opposed to the global abort I am looking for and which can happen anytime, in any test (i.e. deep, deep in library code). I certainly don't want to depend all tests on their predecessor tests' passed/failed status just for this. And it also would lead to other "branches" of the dependency tree being executed anyways.

So how can I abort the complete test set execution programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Well.....you could set a flag value as EXIT,before doing exit test.....and either return this flag to the calling function or driver script/function...and if that's not possible, you could  write the flag value into a temporary file, and make ur driver script read this file before it moves to the next Test set.....

Comment: I would need to check (or pass-through to the caller) the exit flag after every action call (or every function call that triggers an action call - we´re talking generic code here). That´s what I want to avoid.